# What is the proper way to plot spectrum of a complex signal sampled in a narrow range?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft

I have some complex data (small bandwidth around a set frequency) that I'm curious to plot, but I am slightly lost as to how should I proceed about interpreting a complex signal sampled in a particular range.

So, for instance, here is the code (and my rather poor attempt at the problem) that I wrote so I have a clean example to experiment with artificial signal, that generates complex representation of 78 KHz wave. What I am trying to do is to get a plot that is centred at 120 KHz, and spans from 70 to 170 KHz, mimicking narrow sampling range of the real receiver.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#sampling rate, samples/second; 100 KHz
rate = 100*10**3
#sample spacing in time, seconds/sample
interval = np.true_divide(1, rate)
#length of the fourier transform
n = 256
#time vector
t = np.linspace(0.0, n*interval, n)

#frequency of artificial signal; 78 KHz
f = 78*10**3
#complex signal
s = np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*f*t)

#dft of the data
dft = np.fft.fft(s)
#frequency bins
x = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=interval)
#center zero-frequency component in data; take absolute values
dft = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(dft))
#center zero frequency component in bins; naively add the center frequency, 120 KHz
x = np.fft.fftshift(x) + 120*10**3

plt.plot(x, dft)
plt.show()
```

The output, is wrong, as expected with the crude attempt to mimic particular frequency range.

[Plot made by the code snippet above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbrna.png)

P.S. [Different plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Gp0.png) , with `f = 88*10*83` - why has the magnitude changed here, suddenly?

Edit: My post has been marked for duplicated with a topic related purely to plotting, while what I'm actually after is processing and/or inversion of bandpass-filtered data.

Comment: No, that's not a duplicate of that for sure. We're talking about NumPy/SciPy processing of complex time-domain data recorded through a bandpass filter .

Comment: If I remember correctly about FT, it's the integral that's conserved, not the peak magnitude. So that answers your side-question: the second peak is narrower, so it must be higher.

Answer (score 8):

#### Nyquist Frequency and Aliasing

Your signal should be a (complex) exponential oscillation at +78 kHz, sampled at 100 kHz. [This doesn't work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency). What you see instead is an alias frequency at -22 kHz (78 kHz - 100 kHz). You have to make sure that *no frequency of your signal is higher than half your sampling frequency*. For a signal of 78 kHz take a sample frequency of 200 kHz, for example.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sample_frequency = 200e3  # 200 kHz
sample_interval = 1 / sample_frequency
samples = 256  # you don't necessarily have to use a power of 2
time = np.linspace(0, samples*sample_interval, samples)

signal_frequency = 78e3  # 78 kHz
signal = np.exp(2j*np.pi*signal_frequency*time)
```

#### FFT and `fftfreq`

[`np.fft.fftfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) already returns the right frequencies, adding a "center frequency" mekes no sense. Don't do it.

```
signal_spectrum = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(signal))
freqs = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(samples, d=sample_interval))
```

#### Plotting

The plotting part of your question is only about setting the axes. Use [`plt.xlim`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim).

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(freqs / 1e3, np.abs(signal_spectrum))  # in kHz
plt.xlim(70, 170)
```

[image: Signal spectrum]

The plotted line ends just before 100 kHz, because as mentioned above your signal cannot have a frequency part higher than your half sample frequency.

#### Magnitude of spectrum

Since your signal is time-discrete (several single samples, not a continuous function), your spectrum is continuous. The [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), however, only returns discrete samples of the continuous spectrum. If you would fit a curve through the sampling points, its peak would have the same magnitude for different frequencies.

Alternatively, you could increase the number of FFT sampling points by *zero-padding* your signal (take a look at the [`numpy.fft.fft` documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html)):

```
signal_spectrum = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(signal, 10*samples))
freqs = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(10*samples, d=sample_interval))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(freqs / 1e3, np.abs(signal_spectrum))  # in kHz
plt.xlim(65, 95).
plt.grid()
```

[image: Spectrum of zero-padded signal with leakage]

If you're asking yourself why the spectrum looks so rippled, Take a look at [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I'll take it to [DSPSE](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/), since answer of the sort you provided is not necessarily helpful.